# Close CartoDB Infowindow from Template

Tags: javascript, carto

I have seen the different solutions that store the info window in a variable and close it from outside of the info window, however I would like to have a possibility to close the info window from within itself, like having a button that closes the info window (in addition to the close button). I have seen that I can add the close class to an element, however this also adds the default styling, which I don't want.

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/xavijam/7283a403afb6a54eda9a) on how to close programmatically an Infowindow. You only need to attach that code to the proper event for your use case, being a keystroke, a button in your infowindow or outside, etc.

Comment: Thanks, but this is the example I referenced to above as well. How would you use this in a "clean" way, from inside the template? Currently, I put a method into the global window object to reference from the template, which is probably the worst solution. I have more than one sublayer, with infowindows which makes all that a bit more tricky as well.

Comment: Check [this other example](http://bl.ocks.org/jsanz/d6831b16303567c2af07) on templating infowindows. You can attach any logic to your infowindow. Hope this completes my answer.

Comment: Hi Jorge, no I have custom templates and I know how to programmatically close an infowindow. The question is about, how to do it in the infowindow without ugly hacks. I need to put the infowindow reference into a global js variable to retrieve it from the infowindow. This works, but it is horrible code, so I was hoping for a good solution like writing in the infowindow `this.setVisibility('false' )`, which does not work BTW.

Comment: You have a place to run code when the infowindow is created. You don't have to attach it to a global variable, but that depends on parts where CartoDB.js is not having an opinion. If you are coding a Backbone app for example, you will have a place where you store your map model, you can save there a reference to your infowindow and then offer a service to change its visibility.

Comment: Ah, you are right, I haven't thought about that. That would indeed work, thanks.

Comment: Happy to clarify @Robin \o/